# Can i add facebook appId through java code rather than add in manifest(API 4)

Tags: java, android, facebook-sdk-4.0

```
    <provider
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider455621177938568"
        android:exported="true" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
```

Can i initialize these app id in the activity class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-Hello 
-Yes you can do it By adding your app id through `Session`

-Here is the sample code for it :-

```
String appidstring="Your app id";

Session session = new Session.Builder(getBaseContext()).setApplicationId(appidstring).build();

Session.setActiveSession(session);

if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
    session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
}
```

--------Update---------------------

-Sorry i forgot in **facebook sdk v4** as per this document [Upgrading from older version session class has been removed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4.x)

-If you want to set app id programatically ...You can set it as

`FacebookSdk.setApplicationId(APP_ID);`

-Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but in sdk 4 there is no Session class :( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/